# Objective c : How to set time and progress of uiprogressview dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, uiprogressview

Say I have a UIProgressBar with size (394,129,328,9) and I increased the height with

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 3.0f);
PgView.transform = transform;
```

What I need to implement is : If I have 5 minute time,the progressView should be filled with a certain amount and totally filled at the end of 5 minute. Same for 1 minute and 30 minutes too.

I am implementing like this :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 3.0f);
    PgView.transform = transform;

    recievedData = 0.01;
    xpectedTotalSize = 1.0;
    PgView.progress = 0.0;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)makeMyProgressBarMoving
{
    float actual = [PgView progress];
    if (actual < 1)
    {
        PgView.progress = actual + ((float)recievedData/(float)xpectedTotalSize);
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    else{

    }
}
```

And it works. But I want to implement progress and time interval dynamically? Any idea??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's difficult to understand your intention. As I suppose, you want to update the progress bar only if new values are available instead of updating with a fixed timer interval.

This would result in the simple answer: update your progress bar whenever you change the value of 'recievedData'. So, the method 'makeMyProgressBarMoving' doesn't need a timer. Also, you don't need to remember the 'actual' value. You can directly assign the 'receivedData/xpectedTotalSize' to the progress bar.

```
- (void) updateProgressBar
{
    PgView.progress =  ((float)receivedData/(float)xpectedTotalSize);
}

- (void) updateReceivedData
{
    if (receivedData < 20)
        receivedData += 1.0;
    else
        receivedData += 10.0;

    [self updateProgressBar];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    receivedData = 0.0;
    xpectedTotalSize = 100.0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateReceivedData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Now, a timer is still used for demonstration to call 'updateReceivedData' which just increments 'receivedData' and calls 'updateProgressBar'. As you see, 'updateReceivedData' does not increment linear, again just for demonstration. If 'updateReceivedData' would be called on demand instead by the timer then also the progress bar would be updated on demand. Now it's just an issue of how and when you want to update your receivedData. It's not an issue regarding progress bars.

Comment: Thank you, after cast my values, progress view started updating