# Why does UIProgressView not update?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiprogressview

I'm trying to set the progress of a UIProgressView, but the progressView doesn't "update".
Why? Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code in ViewController.h:

```
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;
```

That's the code in ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

progressBar.progress = 0.0;

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(progressUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];


}

-(void)progressUpdate {

float actual = [progressBar progress];
if (actual < 1) {
    progressBar.progress = actual + 0.1;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self `selector:@selector(progressUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`
}
else {

}

}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to set `repeat` to `YES`.

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(progressUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: @Prince: no he don't, because he is repeatedly calling the same method. It'll again creating a timer, so no need to set the timer repeat to yes.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `[progressBar setProgress:<value> animated:YES];` instead of `progressBar.progress = <value>`

EDIT: Take a look at this, which looks a lot like your example: [Objective c : How to set time and progress of uiprogressview dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759243/objective-c-how-to-set-time-and-progress-of-uiprogressview-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Double check that progressBar is linked correctly in Interface Builder.

If it still doesn't work, try using `[progressBar setProgress:0];` and `[progressBar setProgress:actual+0.1];`.

Also know that the UIProgressView has a `[progressBar setProgress:<value> animated:YES];` method. May look cleaner.

Comment: He is repeatedly calling the same method. It'll again creating a timer, so no need to set the timer repeat to yes.

Comment: What does "linked correctly" mean for you?? The same like for other outlets(textfields, labels, buttons...)??

Comment: Exactly! You can't modify an object in the Interface Builder if it isn't linked to the object ;).

Answer (score 1):

Its should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progressBar.progress = 0.0;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(progressUpdate) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)progressUpdate {
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(1/(float)i)] waitUntilDone:YES];   
    }
}

- (void)setProgress:(NSNumber *)number
{
   [progressBar setProgress:number.floatValue animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this morning. It appeared that the progressBar was partly over a UITableView. I moved it a little, so that it was not overlapping anymore.

I'm not sure why this is. It should have been working in the original case, but that is how I solved it.